# How to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode3.2, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a Tab Bar with a navigation table view. My app crashes when I select a cell on my table view. I want a new viewcontroller to open when a cell is selected. My guess is that I am not pushing it correctly when didselectrowatindexpath is called. The app stays hung up for a few seconds then closes.

Does anything catch your eye with this code? Or do you have any sample code? I am using Xcode 3 with simulator 4.3.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
        if (self.vailViewController == nil) {
            VailViewController *vailView = [[VailViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"View" bundle:nil];
            self.vailViewController = vailView;
            [vailView release];
        }

        vailViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [resortsArray  objectAtIndex:row]];
        Ski_AdvisorAppDelegate *delegate = (Ski_AdvisorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication  sharedApplication] delegate];
        [delegate.resortsNavController pushViewController:vailViewController animated:YES];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd assume vailViewController is a @property (retain)?

Comment: also, what is aBookDetail?  Was that supposed to be vailView?

Comment: Does it give any kind of error?

Comment: Your code here is fine, as far as I can tell. We need to see how the **self.vailViewController** property is defined. Also, it would be **extremely** helpful if you could also provide the specific error message/stack trace that appears when the application crashes.

Comment: The debugger is telling me this when it crashes. 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (self.vailViewController == nil) {
        VailViewController *vailView = [[VailViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"View" bundle:nil];
        self.vailViewController = vailView;
        [vailView release];
    }
```

In this block of code is your view file actually named "View.xib" because if not this is your crash. With this error message

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'View''

So if you want to load this with initWithNibName and your files are named as such:

VailViewController.h
VailViewController.m
VailViewController.xib

you need:

```
VailViewController *vailView = [[VailViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"VailViewController" bundle:nil];
```

However if it is a standard UIViewController subclass you should only need to do:

```
VailViewController *vailView = [[VailViewController alloc] init];
```

The above works if you just created a UIViewController subclass in Xcode and didn't change anything.  The view controller knows how to load it's own view.  If you had it create an .xib file for you and you deleted something in it or just arn't sure make sure the File's Owner is wired up to the root view in the .xib file in interface bulder.

I hope that helps.

**Edit:**

The error in your comments:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported

is coming these two lines in your code:

```
[delegate.resortsNavController pushViewController:vailViewController animated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vailViewController animated:YES];
```

I should ask if these are two different navigation controllers?  if so why do they need the exact same view controller pushed to them?

I would remove one of them and then it should push the view controller without error.

Comment: Thank you- I tried both of those and it didn't work. I am getting this error in the debugger

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported

Comment: based on the debugger info added to my answer by John, I think this is likely the correct answer.  The exception complains about not finding "View"

Comment: @John - don't save the controller off then.  Try creating it each time.  If you're worried about perf later, look into UINib

Comment: i updated the answer, the problems seems to be the bottom of your block pushing to two ( or the same ) navigation controller twice.. and if you actually need to do that do you need to animate it both times?

Comment: You have no idea how happy I was when that viewcontroller loaded. thanks guys. I appreciate. It worked when i took one of those out. It didn't matter which one.

Answer (score 0):

What is aBookDetail? It seems like you might not be pushing the VailViewController onto the stack like you think you are. The code below might be more what you want. Also, does the debugger give you any error information about the crash?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    if (self.vailViewController == nil) {
        VailViewController *vailView = [[VailViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"View" bundle:nil];
        self.vailViewController = vailView;
        [vailView release];
    }

    self.vailViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [resortsArray  objectAtIndex:row]];
    Ski_AdvisorAppDelegate *delegate = (Ski_AdvisorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication  sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate.resortsNavController pushViewController:self.vailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: my bad about aBookDetail.. i forgot to switch that when i copied it over it should be vailView

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the vailViewController is being retained.

```
@property (retain) VailViewController *vailViewController;
```

Also, is the resortsNavController off of Ski_AdvisorAppDelegate retained?  How is that property defined?

Also, is the UITableViewController the rootController of the UINavigationController?  If so, you should be able to call [self navigationController]

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailedView animated:YES];
```

I typically do this in my appDelegate:

```
_mainTableViewController = [[MainTableViewController alloc] init];
_navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_mainTableViewController];
```

Comment: Well I retained the VailView Controller in the tableviewcontroller that this code is in. The tableview is the root. i have resortsnavconrtoller retained in my delegate-thanks again for your help

Comment: Here is some more from the debugger:
        *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception             'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/KingJohnLanz/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/E038D880-31F0-40FA-9AC9-4F54F5093933/Ski Advisor.app> (loaded)' with name 'View''

Comment: It looks like you gave the wrong name in your initWithNibName:@"View",  I posted a more detailed answer here.

Comment: I didn't give that name - that's in John's question.  I think you're right though ...

Comment: yeah, i wanted to comment on his comment and not your answer. sorry.  it was just a response to the error message he posted.